# Query is not working as expected

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following problem performin a query in C#

I have the following method performing a simple query:

```
    public List<DataModel.Vulnerability.VulnerabilitySolution> getVulnerabilitySolutionsList(int vulnId)
    {
        List<DataModel.Vulnerability.VulnerabilitySolution> result = new List<Vulnerability.VulnerabilitySolution>();

        System.Data.Common.DbCommand command;
        command = _connection.CreateCommand();
        command.Connection = this._connection;

        _strSQL = "VS.* FROM VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilitySolution VAD_VS"
                  + " INNER JOIN VulnerabilitySolution VS ON VAD_VS.VulnerabilitySolutionId = VS.Id"
                  + " WHERE VAD_VS.VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId = @VULNID ";

        addParameter(command, "@VULNID", vulnId);

        command.CommandText = _strSQL;
        _dt = fillDataTable(command);

        DataModel.Vulnerability.VulnerabilitySolution vulnSolution;

        foreach (DataRow row in _dt.Rows)
        {
            vulnSolution = new DataModel.Vulnerability.VulnerabilitySolution(row);
            result.Add(vulnSolution);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The problem is that when try to execute this line: **_dt = fillDataTable(command);** it throw the following exception: **Incorrect syntax near '*'**

What could be the problem? If I try to execute the same query in SQL Server (replacing the value of the parameter) it work fine

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Your are missing `SELECT` keyword. `SELECT VS.* FROM ......`

Comment: Looks like there are some new close types I hadn't noticed being added. Vote to close because this looks like a simply typo error.

Comment: @Dash Funny though, the OP didn't even have a chance to see if that fixed the entire issue before it was closed.

Comment: @PortlandRunner we can take it off hold if this turns out not to be the case. Fair point, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the word select before the VS.*

```
  _strSQL = "SELECT VS.* FROM VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilitySolution VAD_VS"
                  + " INNER JOIN VulnerabilitySolution VS ON VAD_VS.VulnerabilitySolutionId = VS.Id"
                  + " WHERE VAD_VS.VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId = @VULNID ";
```

Comment: Nah, it is one of those things that you can look at forever and easily overlook.  We've all been there